# matching specific character strings as word patterns in a corpus in R

Tags: string-matching

I need your help. I have a corpus in R and i want to find specific words in it. The final line of my code is this 
sentences_with_args <- arg.match(c("because", "however", "therefore"),myCorpus, 0). 
Problem is that apart from the words mentioned above R returns several words that derive from these like "**how**" from "**however**" and **"cause"** from **"because"**. How do i match the specific strings to their exact occurrences in the corpus? Thank you.